# Process Scheduling Information Extraction

Tags: ps, top

I want to extract the process having highest utilization on each processor core
and then output its information (PID etc.) to a file. How can I do it by using either top or ps command?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
ps -k -pcpu -O pcpu,psr
```

The k flag is your sort key which is percent CPU. Capital O changes the output to add the percent CPU utilisation and the current processor/cpu the process ran on. You get output like:

```
  PID %CPU PSR S TTY          TIME COMMAND
15049  5.8   2 S tty2     00:00:28 chrome
14808  4.3   1 S tty2     00:00:21 chrome
14448  3.9   5 S tty2     00:00:21 gnome-shell
15234  1.8   5 S tty2     00:00:08 chrome
14896  1.5   2 S tty2     00:00:07 chrome
14322  1.2   0 S tty2     00:00:06 Xorg
```

percent cpu is the time column divided by the real time. You may get odd results if you have a busy process that then idles (but its average overall is still high or low, depending on what you were expecting).

To get something to answer "what's keeping my CPU busy in the last few seconds" then top is a better tool.

Also note, the processes will bounce around on the CPUs, so nailing down why a CPU runs hot can sometimes be tricky to work out. You generally want this to spread the load across them.

Answer (score 2):

```
PSOUTFILE=/tmp/ps-out.txt
ps -ef| sort -r  -k7 | head -2 >> ${PSOUTFILE}
```

this above segment gets the top one process' information and the header line explaining what each column refers to and writes to the file specified. If you do not want to print the column header line, you can modify it as such:

```
PSOUTFILE=/tmp/ps-out.txt
ps -ef| sort -r  -k7 | head -2 | tail -1 >> ${PSOUTFILE}
```

If this is not what you are looking for, you need to be more detailed in your question. Please modify your original post to include more details, explaining what you want to see in this file.

Comment: This is very close to what I am looking for. For example, when I run two processes each having 99% CPU utilization on cores 0 and 1, "ps -ef| sort -r  -k7 | head -2 >> ${PSOUTFILE}" prints out both the processes successfully, except for the cores they are running on. How can I get the information that on which core these processes are executing on as well using your command?

Comment: You need to specify the option `psr` of the `ps` command. Please see `/usr/share/doc/procps-3.2.8/FAQ` on your system to understand how these options work, as specifying one, changes the output of your ps command drastically. I do not have much experience using `ps` in such ways. Hence I can not be of any further help